# Not asking admin to enter password for password protected pages

Tags: wordpress

I am using the password protection feature from WordPress

https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Password_Protection

to protect my pages with password.

So now when I see the page in front-end it asks for password no matter who is logged in. I was wondering if there is any way so that, admin can directly view the website on front-end without having to enter the password. But other users must.

I guess this is not possible. But still I want to be sure about it. So kindly let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
add_filter( 'post_password_required', 'remove_password_requirement_for_admins', 0 );
function remove_password_requirement_for_admins( $required ) {
    if ( current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ) {
        $required = false;
    }

    return $required;
}
```

Add this to your theme's `functions.php`.

Comment: Thanks. It works. But I get a Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'remove_password_requirement_for_admins' not found or invalid function name in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php on line 300

Comment: Not sure why that is. I'm using this on a clean theme, and I get no warnings.

What's your WordPress version?

Comment: Oh. thanks for the clarification. Tried with another theme and it worked perfectly.